# Spring WS: Add custom SOAP header in wsdl request

Tags: java, web-services, spring-boot, soap, wsdl

What's my goal?

I am trying to expose the soap service using 'UWLR_Leerlinggegevens_v2p2.xsd' and it is including other xsds also :
below exposed WSDL missing soap: header in ws:input hence while importing wsdl into SOAP UI Header part not coming

```
<wsdl:operation name="leerkrachten">
    <soap:operation soapAction="" />
    <wsdl:input name="leerkrachten_verzoek">
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
    </wsdl:input>
    <wsdl:output name="leerkrachten_antwoord">
        <soap:body use="literal" />
    </wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
```

I need solution for how to add header part in

What's the problem?

Here is my code :

```
    @EnableWs
    @Configuration
    @ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = { WebServiceConfig.class })
    public class WebServiceConfig extends WsConfigurerAdapter {


    private static final String[] WS_URL_MAPPINGS = { "*.wsdl", "*.xsd"};
        @Bean
        public ServletRegistrationBean messageDispatcherServlet(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
            MessageDispatcherServlet servlet = new MessageDispatcherServlet();
            servlet.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
            servlet.setTransformWsdlLocations(true);

            return new ServletRegistrationBean(servlet, WS_URL_MAPPINGS);
        }

        @Bean(name = "leerlinggegevens")
        public DefaultWsdl11Definition defaultWsdl11Definition() {
            DefaultWsdl11Definition wsdl11Definition = new DefaultWsdl11Definition();
            wsdl11Definition.setPortTypeName("leerlinggegevensPort");
            wsdl11Definition.setLocationUri("/ws");
            wsdl11Definition.setTargetNamespace("http://www.edustandaard.nl/leerresultaten/2/leerlinggegevens/");
            wsdl11Definition.setSchemaCollection(xsdSchemaCollection());
            wsdl11Definition.setRequestSuffix("_verzoek");
            wsdl11Definition.setResponseSuffix("_antwoord");
            wsdl11Definition.setFaultSuffix(":Fault");
            return wsdl11Definition;
        }


        @Bean
        public CommonsXsdSchemaCollection xsdSchemaCollection() {
            CommonsXsdSchemaCollection xsds = new CommonsXsdSchemaCollection(new Resource[] {
                    new ClassPathResource("Schemas/UWLR_Autorisatie_v2p2.xsd"),
                    new ClassPathResource("Schemas/SOAP_Envelope.xsd"),
                    new ClassPathResource("Schemas/EDEXML.types.vast.xsd"),
                    new ClassPathResource("Schemas/EDEXML.types.variabel.xsd"),
                    new ClassPathResource("Schemas/EDEXML.elementen.xsd"),
                    new ClassPathResource("Schemas/UWLR_Leerlinggegevens_v2p2.xsd")});
            xsds.setInline(true);
            return xsds;    
        }
    }
```

also tried with SimpleWsdl11Definition to expose the direct wsdl instead of using xsd

```
@Bean(name = "leerlinggegevens")
    public Wsdl11Definition defaultWsdl11Definition() {
        SimpleWsdl11Definition wsdl11Definition = new SimpleWsdl11Definition();
        wsdl11Definition.setWsdl(new ClassPathResource("wsdl/UWLR_Leerlinggegevens_v2p2.wsdl"));

        return wsdl11Definition;
    }
```

but facing issue while import into SOAP UI becasue original wsdl referring other xsds as below

```
<wsdl:types>
<xs:schema>
<xs:import schemaLocation="../Schemas/UWLR_Leerlinggegevens_v2p2.xsd" namespace="http://www.edustandaard.nl/leerresultaten/2/leerlinggegevens"/>
<xs:import schemaLocation="../Schemas/UWLR_Autorisatie_v2p2.xsd" namespace="http://www.edustandaard.nl/leerresultaten/2/autorisatie"/>
</xs:schema>
</wsdl:types>
```

using SimpleWsdl11Definition i dont know how to add other xsds

Comment: expected out put : <wsdl:operation name="HaalLeerkrachten">
<soap:operation soapAction="http://www.edustandaard.nl/leerresultaten/2/leerlinggegevens/leerkrachten_verzoek"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap:header message="lg:msgHeader" part="msgpHeader" use="literal"/>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>

Comment: actual output coming as : <wsdl:operation name="leerkrachten">
<soap:operation soapAction=""/>
<wsdl:input name="leerkrachten_verzoek">
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output name="leerkrachten_antwoord">
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation> -> missing header part in <wsdl:input><soap:header message="lg:msgHeader" part="msgpHeader" use="literal"/></wsdl:input>

Comment: Please don't add additional information as comments, edit your question instead. It is also unclear to me if you really want add headers to the request (incoming) or the response (outgoing)..

Comment: I need to add headers to the request (incoming)

Comment: You cannot, as the client needs to send those... So if you don't send them from SOAP ui or whatever client you are using, you cannot (and shouldn't) add them auto magically.

Comment: below exposed wsdl missing <soap:header> that Iam expecting here

<wsdl:operation name="leerkrachten">
 <soap:operation soapAction="" />
 <wsdl:input name="leerkrachten_verzoek">
  <soap:body use="literal" />
 </wsdl:input>
 <wsdl:output name="leerkrachten_antwoord">
  <soap:body use="literal" />
 </wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>

Comment: As mentioned before, don't post additional information as comments, edit your question instead. Currently all the added information is totally unreadable.

Comment: Also adding SOAP headers without changing the WSDL is obviously not going to work. You cannot create something that doesn't adhere to the contract (the WSDL and XSD).

Comment: Now i edited the post

Comment: If this a WSDL you got from an external party why do you want to change it.

Comment: Its just standard Netherland govt provided some standard way to communicating the publishers and consumers through that wsdl or xsd using that xsd I am trying to expose the wsdl then my clients will connect with this endpoint and we provide the data to clients

Comment: I still don't see why you need to change the WSDL. You already have it then expose it, don't try to re-generate it. Which is what you are doing with the `DefaultWsdl11Definition`. Just expose the given WSDL which should contain everything you need.

Comment: tried that also but facing issue while adding into soap ui because its importing external xsds